# Webview onReceivedHttpError and onReceivedError problem (not working)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview

i will try to handel webview onReceivedError and onReceivedHttpError, i will show error laytout when webview ReceivedError or ReceivedHttpError and hide webview and when user refresh than error layout hide and webview show but problem is webview onReceivedError is work correctly but onReceivedHttpError not working means error layout not showing webview directly show error, please help me ...

i will get some http errors which will display on webview directly :- net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE..

this is my code :-

```
override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
                binding.progressBar.progress = newProgress
                if (newProgress == 100) {
                    view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.errorLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                }

                if (newProgress > 70) {
                    binding.swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                } else {
                    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
```

onReceivedError code :-

```
override fun onReceivedError(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?,
                error: WebResourceError?
            ) {
                if (error != null && error.errorCode != -1) {
                    val errorCode = error.errorCode
                    val errorMessage = error.description.toString()
                    binding.errorLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.webView.visibility = View.GONE
                    isErrorOccurred = true
                    handleError(errorCode, errorMessage)
                }
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
            }
```

onReceivedHttpError code :-

```
override fun onReceivedHttpError(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?,
                errorResponse: WebResourceResponse?
            ) {
                if (errorResponse != null && errorResponse.statusCode != 404) {
                    val errorCode = errorResponse.statusCode
                    val errorMessage = errorResponse.reasonPhrase.toString()
                    binding.errorLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.webView.visibility = View.GONE
                    isErrorOccurred = true
                    handleError(errorCode, errorMessage)
                }
                super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse)
            }
```

```
fun handleError(errorCode: Int?, errorDes: String) {
        var message: String? = null
        when (errorCode) {
            WebViewClient.ERROR_AUTHENTICATION -> message = "User authentication failed on server"
            WebViewClient.ERROR_TIMEOUT -> message =
                "The server is taking too much time to communicate. Try again later."

            WebViewClient.ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS -> message = "Too many requests during this load"
            WebViewClient.ERROR_UNKNOWN -> message = "Generic error"
            WebViewClient.ERROR_BAD_URL -> message = "Check entered URL.."
            WebViewClient.ERROR_CONNECT -> message = "Failed to connect to the server"
            WebViewClient.ERROR_FAILED_SSL_HANDSHAKE -> message = "Failed to perform SSL handshake"
            WebViewClient.ERROR_HOST_LOOKUP -> message = "Server or proxy hostname lookup failed"
            WebViewClient.ERROR_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION -> message =
                "User authentication failed on proxy"

            WebViewClient.ERROR_REDIRECT_LOOP -> message = "Too many redirects"
            WebViewClient.ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_AUTH_SCHEME -> message =
                "Unsupported authentication scheme (not basic or digest)"

            WebViewClient.ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_SCHEME -> message = "unsupported scheme"
            WebViewClient.ERROR_FILE -> message = "Generic file error"
            WebViewClient.ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND -> message = "File not found"
            WebViewClient.ERROR_IO -> message = "The server failed to communicate. Try again later."
        }

        binding.errorTxt1.text = errorDes
        binding.errorTxt2.text = message

    }
```